# AngularJS: How do I watch for changes in data returned from a REST call?

Tags: rest, angularjs

What's the best way to keep a model updated in Angular if the model is being populated by data fetched via an HTTP GET?

Comment: You will need to just call your function in the controller at some interval. In the model it automatically gets updated or else you can use $watch.

Comment: Not sure, I understand your question. If you just set the result of the rest call into your scope, it will get automatically watched by any bindings in your template. to update it you can simply overwrite it whenever you do your next REST call.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on whether you're asking how to consume an HTTP GET call to retrieve data for a model, or how to refresh it to keep it updated.

In the former case, just build a call using `$http`:

```
$scope.yourModel = null;

$http.get({
    url: "/your/url/"
}).success(data) {
    $scope.yourModel = data;
}
```

In the later, you just need a timeout to periodically trigger the same request:

```
$timeout(function() {

    $http.get()...

}, 30000); // Load every 30 seconds
```